# php string concatenation "A<"."B" does not work

Tags: php, html, string, string-concatenation

I'm writing a function to output HTML elements, the problem is: when I try to concatenate this two strings:

```
$tag = "<" . "tag";
```

The instruction echo `$tag` outputs nothing. What is wrong

Comment: `<` is parsed by the browser. Use `&lt;` instead

Comment: Jake you're actually right. I misread the question

Comment: @m_junior can you provide more context in your question?

Comment: @m_junior Yes please more context and maybe a but more code. Because if you print what is there the tag would be broken in any case so i guess there is more to it then just that line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, special characters like `<`, will be parsed by browser as HTML, therefore you won't see them as you expect.

Its almost the same thing:

```
$tag = 'p';

echo '<' . $tag '>' . Test . '</' . $tag . '>';
```

Which is the same as

```
echo '<p>' . Test . '</p>';
```

So after script execution you'll see just

```
Test
```

in a browser. but when viewing a source, it will be as

```
<p>Test</p>
```

If for some reason you want to see HTML tags, then you need to escape special chars using built-in function `htmlentities()`.

In your case, you can just prepare a string, then just echo it like

```
echo htmlentities($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

If by tag you mean an HTML entity then its not going to be seen in the browser. You may need to do a 'view source' to see what was created by echo call.